# How to make a Dictionary and Utility in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 15 web pages that has the same labels. But, in one case, I need to change all of their Text, in all pages. Other than writing them all by one, I want to make something general and public that I can use in all the pages. The ID's of the labels are same. I don't know how to do it with different web pages. Can you give me a hint? I don't know if its called Utility or Dictionary. A friend of mine mentioned it a few mins ago but I don't want to ask her again she already thinks I am dumb :(

They are ASP.NET pages with C# also I am using Devexpress.
I want to change only one web page at a time. But use the method for all web pages when they are shown (by the user). Not changing all the 15 at the same time.

Comment: Web pages? are you using ASP.NET? If so, please add the appropriate tags to your question.

Comment: You cannot change all labels on all webforms at once, because only one page can be shown at the same time. A page exists only when it is requested and only as long as it is not sent to the client. You are mixing webforms and winforms. You should use a dbms or any other kind of storage. Then you can set the `Text` of all your labels to the same record when their pages are requested.

Comment: I updated my question again. It wasnt clear. I don't want it to change them all at the same time, just when it is needed, I want it to change only the working page (only one page)

Comment: @Ada: What kind of information is shown on the labels, are they the same for every user? If so, you could use the [ASP.NET Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the informations shown on the `labels` are the same for every user, you could use the [ASP.NET Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx).

- [How to: Add Items to the Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx)
- [How to: Retrieve Values of Cached Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhy3h9f9.aspx)

If not, you could use the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

But normally you would use a [dbms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system) for this purpose, for example SQL-Server.

**Note**: Do not use the Label's ID as Keys for the Cache/Session/Database but the meaning. ID's may change, apart from that it's much more readable.